# Is it possible to use XSD to define incrementally specified tree structure?

Tags: xml, validation, graph, tree, xsd

Let's say we have an element which is either a leaf (containing some value) or a composite (a usual composite pattern). I want to model tree instances which are expected to be refined by other instances for example by filling a composite node with new elements. I want to be able to decide whether one tree instance conforms to another instance by its structure. Is it possible to model the instance as a XSD and implement the conformance as XSD conforming to other XSDs? Note there is more than just two levels - each structure can serve as a meta-structure.

Appendix: For better picture of the intent here are some the possible rules.

- "This composite is not extensible (is fixed)."
- "You can add elements at the end of this composite."
- "This composite contains an optional leaf 1 and a mandatory leaf 2."
- "This composite contains an arbitrary number of occurrences of that composite."

Examples:

```
Structure 1:
composite
    0..1 "abc"
    1..n "def"
    0..n extensible composite "c1"
        1..1 "ghi"
    0..1 composite "c2"
        1..1 "jkl"

Structure 2:
composite
    1..1 "def"
    1..1 "def"
    1..1 "def"
    1..1 extensible composite "c1"
        1..1 "ghi"
        1..n "extension"
    1..n extensible composite "c1"
        1..1 "ghi"

Structure 3:
composite
    0..n "abc" //too many "abc"s
    //"def" needed
    0..1 composite "c2"
        1..1 "jkl"
        1..1 "mno" //forbidden extension
```

The second structure conforms to the first one, the third one does not. I thought maybe that could be expressed with schema validation.

Comment: It's not completely clear what you're asking, and how XSD factors into the question.  Some sample instances would probably help.

Answer (score 1):

If you're discovering XSD, it always help to start by crafting a bunch of XML files, representative to what you're trying to achieve, to feed them **all at the same time** to a tool that can generate one (or more) XSD files (depending if you use multiple namespaces or not). Once you have a reasonable base in XSD, you could tackle that manually.

This is what I've tried based on your clarifications.

Sample1.xml

```
<composite>
    <abc/>
    <def/>
    <c1>
        <ghi/>
    </c1>
    <c1>
        <ghi/>
    </c1>
    <c2>
        <jkl/>
    </c2>
</composite>
```

Sample2.xml

```
<composite>
    <def/>
    <def/>
    <c1>
        <ghi/>
        <extension/>
    </c1>
    <c1>
        <ghi/>
    </c1>   
</composite>
```

Based on the above, the original generated XSD is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--XML Schema generated by QTAssistant/XML Schema Refactoring (XSR) Module (http://www.paschidev.com)-->
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="composite">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="abc" type="xs:anyType" />
        <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="def" type="xs:anyType" />
        <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="c1">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="ghi" type="xs:anyType" />
              <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="extension" type="xs:anyType" />
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="c2">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="jkl" type="xs:anyType" />
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

It requires some tweaking, since all of the cardinality scenarios you've described were not captured by the XMLs. Below is an updated diagram, for easier reconciliation to the original markup.

[image]

It should be easier to see how the XSD seems to match what you've asked (where cardinality is not shown, assume (1..1) - which is the default for particles in XSD).

How extensions are to be further defined, maybe through the use of other mechanism such as wild card elements, or constrained to be based on a base type, are activities to be done based on further requirements. If you're getting into even more sophisticated scenarios, such as having a mandatory presence based on other element presence or values (co-constraints), then XSD 1.0 may not work...

This should get you started at least to provide additional details for your question...